# Switch FileSystemWatcher on and off to avoid multiple instances

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Newbee alert. Problem: I populate a combo box, user makes a selection. I then create and enable a FSW. All works well, until user revisits combo box to make an alternate selection. At that point, another FSW is instantiated resulting in IO Exceptions based on 'file in use' errors. I need to switch off the FSW (or destroy the instantiation) when the user makes a subsequent selection in the combo box. Entire program is driven from a Winform with the combo box.

How do either toggle the FSW on/off, or destroy the FSW instantiation and allow a new, similar one to be created when the user revisits the combo box and makes another selection?

Code that calls for instantiation of the FSW:

```
        private void MinAndGo()
    {
        if (strLblPtr != null)
        {
            if(strLblPtr != "None")
            {
                if (!CheckMyPrinter(strLblPtr))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ForegroundWindow.Instance, "Printer is not ready. Make sure it's turned on "
                    + "and has paper loaded.", "Printer Not Ready");
                }
            }
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            this.Activate();
            bCreateWatcher = true;
            Watchit();
        }
    }
```

Code for WatchIt(). I was intending on using the bool bCreateWatcher to toggle the FSW on and off.

```
private static void Watchit()
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("C:\\SAMMS\\pcl");
        list.Add("C:\\SAMMS\\lbl");
        foreach (string my_path in list)
        {
            Watch(my_path);
        }
    }
    private static void Watch(string watch_folder)
    {

        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.InternalBufferSize = 8192; //defaults to 4KB, need 8KB buffer
        watcher.Path = watch_folder;
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
       | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
        watcher.Filter = "*.*"; 
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated);
        // Begin watching.
        try
        {
            if (bCreateWatcher)
            {
                watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            }
            else
            {
                watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ForegroundWindow.Instance, "FSW not set correctly" + ex, "FSW Error");
        }
     }
```

Comment: Can you also provide the code for `WatchIt()`?

Comment: I'm new to the forum. The code for WatchIt() is too long for this reply/comment window. I'll try something to get it to you.

Comment: You can edit your existing post, and add it there.

Comment: I'll break it into two or three parts.

Comment: Ok. Learned to edit the question. Duh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it looks like you need to store your watcher somewhere, perhaps a dictionary keyed on the path?  You'll also need to have the class that this is all contained in implement `IDisposable`, so that you can properly call `Dispose()` on any watchers you currently have open with the class is disposed of.  (You should then ensure that the containing class is also properly disposed.)

I would refactor `Watch()` to something like this (could probably be better):

```
private static IDictionary<string, FileSystemWatcher> _openWatchers
    = new Dictionary<string, FileSystemWatcher>();

private static void Watch(string watch_folder)
{
    if (!bCreateWatcher)
    {
        if (_openWatchers.ContainsKey(watch_folder))
        {
            _openWatchers[watch_folder].Dispose();
            _openWatchers.Remove(watch_folder);
        }
        return;
    }

    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    watcher.InternalBufferSize = 8192; //defaults to 4KB, need 8KB buffer
    watcher.Path = watch_folder;
    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
   | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
    watcher.Filter = "*.*"; 
    watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated);
    // Begin watching.
    try
    {
         watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
         _openWatchers[watch_folder] = watcher;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ForegroundWindow.Instance, "FSW not set correctly" + ex, "FSW Error");
    }
 }
```

And your `Dispose()` method:

```
 public void Dispose()
 {
     foreach (FileSystemWatcher fsw in _openWatchers.Values)
     {
          fsw.Dispose();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Very nice. Clean. My recent revision uses a Dictionary method, but this is much nicer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `FileSystemWatcher` implements `IDisposable`. Therefore you should call `Dispose` to destroy the instance.

You can find more information here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.dispose(v=vs.80).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx